# Bullet points in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm trying to build a pdf page using jspdf, manually not from the html, I'm not able to get bullet points in the pdf page, I need the bullet before the text rendered like this `doc.text('/bulletpoint/'+data,60,60);` I've tried "u2022" for the bullet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
doc.text('\u2022 ' + your text here);
```

Comment: I've already tried this, this is the output i get  (þÿ "Bootstrap). (þÿ ") comes in the place of '\u2022 '

Comment: @rbc, it looks like [you need to integrate custom fonts](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF#use-of-utf-8--ttf) in order to use non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF has native inbuilt PDF symbol and Zapfdingbats font so you simply use either the  octal \154 or say for Star of David style just use literal `A`
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802213/10802527

Or simpler use mid height "bullet" from symbol's but may need to use a slightly larger font size

```
    doc.setFontSize(14);
    doc.text('My test page', 0.5, 0.5);

    doc.setFont("Zapfdingbats");
    doc.setFontStyle("normal");
    doc.text("\154 abcdefghijkl", 1, 1);

    doc.setFont("Symbol");
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.text('·', 0.3, 0.5);
```

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zCXJ.png]

Answer (score -2):

Just use an oversized dot. that worked for me perfectly.

Comment: I don't consider this to be an anser...