# How to insert circled numbers (Zapfdingbats) using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF and need to integrate circled numbers. My content will be created directly for the PDF, there is no webside that has to be printed as PDF.

Well, after reading a lot I could figure out that Courier New would be the best font to bring circled numbers into my PDF. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Please explain my mistake and provide a practical solution.

```
let doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'mm', 'a4');
let str = 'Go to ①';

doc.setFont('courier');
doc.setFontSize(22);
doc.text(str, 20, 20);
doc.save('mypdf.pdf');
```

Edit: This code only destroys the visualisation of the text. The circled number doesn't appear in the PDF.

Edit II: With some help of @K-J I found:

[Using Zapfdingbats with jsPDf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333857/using-zapfdingbats-with-jspdf)

But unfortunately, that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Well, your first mistake is saying "doesn't work", which doesn't actually give us any useful information. Did you get _errors_, did simply nothing show up in that place, did you get a different character than the expected one, ...?

Comment: Well, the result is added. Doesn't work means, there is no circled number printed.

Comment: Thanks @K-J, if your note was a hint, I didn't get it.

Comment: Thanks @K-J, that will be helpful when I have to integrate new fonts. For now I didn't find a downloadable font, that supports circled number.

Comment: I did und wrote another EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

Dingbats by name Dang-bits by nature number 2 is the most difficult to set

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.setFont("Zapfdingbats");
doc.text("¬­®¯°", 20, 20, null, null);
```

[image]

Here I used CharMap to copy paste the courier glyphs (webdings and windings are not the same mapping) to translate into Dingbats, there must be easier methods?

[image]

***Silly me, there is an easier method use OCTal to generate them.***
there is a list here but not as octal! https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/zdingbat.txt

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.setFont("Zapfdingbats");
doc.text("\254\255\256\257\260\261\262\263\264\265", 20, 20, null, null);
```

[image]

Here is a rough guide to that numbering
[image]

Comment: How did you figure out the code for the circled numbers?